# How to fix an uid error when it can't find it in the code

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm setting up an anonymous user login using firebase and I typed in my code but when trying to run the app an error message comes up saying:

> Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'uid'

is there a way to fix this solution?

```
Auth.auth().signInAnonymously(completion: { ( User, error) in
        if error == nil{

            print("UserId: \(User!.uid)")

        }else{
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

    })
```

Comment: The first parameter in the closure is obviously `AuthDataResult` and not a user. Please read the documentation.

Comment: What  error am I getting so I can fix it

Comment: It's a type mismatch: ⌥-click on `signInAnonymously` to get the documentation. There is a description what the parameter types in the completion closure are. Or read https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth